# Refreshing jframe and disposing the older frame

Tags: java, swing

I have a java swing program which displays the content of an xml page in a jtable. I need to display the frame to be refreshed after every 1 minute. I need to dispose the old frame and get the new frame displayed after being refreshed

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLTableExample {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new XMLTableExample();
    }

    public XMLTableExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                            .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setOpaque(false);

                Color lav = new Color(220, 220, 250);

                try {
                    table.setModel(new XMLTableModel(new File("Htmll.xml")));
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                    //frame.dispose();

                } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException
                        | IOException | XPathExpressionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                JLabel label=new JLabel("label",JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setText("Service Now Notification");
                label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 30));
                label.setForeground(Color.blue);

                frame.add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);

                JButton aButton = new JButton("submit");

                aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

                scroll.getViewport().setBackground(lav);

                frame.add(scroll);
                frame.add(aButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                int frameWidth = 800;
                int frameHeight = 135;
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

               frame.setBounds((int) screenSize.getWidth() - frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);

               frame.setLocation((int) 220,590);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

    public static class XMLTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Number", "Priority",
                "State", "Assigned", "Description", "Task" };
        private List<MSEntity> rows;

        public XMLTableModel(File file) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
            rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse(file);

            setDocument(dom);
        }

        protected String getMSValue(Node msNode, String name)
                throws XPathExpressionException {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("S[@N='" + name + "']");
            Node sNode = (Node) expression
                    .evaluate(msNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
            return sNode != null ? sNode.getTextContent() : null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        public MSEntity getEntityAtRow(int row) {
            return rows.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            MSEntity entity = getEntityAtRow(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = entity.getNumber();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = entity.getPriority();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = entity.getState();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = entity.getAssigned();
                break;
            case 4:
                value = entity.getDesc();
                break;
            case 5:
                value = entity.getTask();
                break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public void setDocument(Document dom) throws XPathExpressionException {

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/Objs/Obj/MS");
            NodeList nl = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(dom,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
                Node node = nl.item(index);
                String number = getMSValue(node, "Number");
                String priority = getMSValue(node, "Priority");
                String state = getMSValue(node, "State");
                String assigned = getMSValue(node, "Assigned");
                String desc = getMSValue(node, "Short_desc");
                String task = getMSValue(node, "Task");

                MSEntity entity = new MSEntity(number, priority, state,
                        assigned, desc, task);
                rows.add(entity);
            }

            fireTableDataChanged();

        }

        public class MSEntity {
            private final String number;
            private final String priority;
            private final String state;
            private final String assigned;
            private final String desc;
            private final String task;

            public MSEntity(String number, String priority, String state,
                    String assigned, String desc, String task) {
                this.number = number;
                this.priority = priority;
                this.state = state;
                this.assigned = assigned;
                this.desc = desc;
                this.task = task;
            }

            public String getAssigned() {
                return assigned;
            }

            public String getDesc() {
                return desc;
            }

            public String getNumber() {
                return number;
            }

            public String getPriority() {
                return priority;
            }

            public String getState() {
                return state;
            }

            public String getTask() {
                return task;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My xml file is this

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
    <Obj RefId="0">
        <TN RefId="0">
            <T>Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T> 
            <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T> 
            <T>System.Object</T> 
        </TN>
        <MS>
            <S N="Number">INC0811168</S> 
            <S N="Priority">2 - High</S> 
            <S N="State">Assigned</S> 
            <S N="Assigned">New</S> 
            <S N="Short_desc">Review Ad-Hoc Service Request for Lavon A Gudmundson</S> 
            <S N="Task">Catalog Task</S> 
        </MS>
    </Obj>
</Objs>
```

I tried

> frame.dispose() but the frame is not being refreshed

Comment: *" I need to dispose the old frame and get the new frame displayed after being refreshed"* - No, you either need to create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the already visible table or update the current model

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If you want to display the contents of the XML file and update it every minute, why not use a `JTextArea` and update the text as it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

> static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Jframe's repaint(long tm) method.